# how to set button text to "<" in android C#?

Tags: c#, android, android-layout, xamarin, button

I want to set "<" as button text using xml.

**my button is here.**

```
<Button
            android:text="<"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/button1" />
```

[image: See the error]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1091945/34397

Answer (score 0):

Try adding "<" as a string resource, and then using that string.